# Perform math in API.AI text formatting

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm wondering if there's a way to perform some simple math in API.AI's text formatting. Specifically, is there any way I can perform math on a number in a text response?

For example, I have the following intent:
[image: API.AI age intent]

I'd like to respond with something like:

> $age.amount?! You don't look a day over ($age.amount - 11).

Which should yield something like:

> 43? You don't look a day over 32.

Is there any support for this kind of syntax? I can't seem to find documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text response just give you the ability to use the variables without any manipulations.
But you could use a simple webhook to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I know a webhook would work, but if you need to fire an HTTP request to subtract two numbers, you're probably just using the wrong tool. It seems like API.AI just isn't meant for this use case.